# How can Streamlit be displayed in a proper form?

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, jupyter-lab, streamlit

I am using the Streamlit open source framework for creating machine learning web applications. I write the code in Python using JupyterLab, save the code as a '.py' document, and then enter 'streamlit run app.py' in the Anaconda Terminal.

However, the Streamlit page does not manifest in the browser, and instead gives this message:

> 2021-12-29 13:18:09.763 INFO    numexpr.utils: NumExpr defaulting to 8
> threads.

I am not sure how to go about this problem. I would truly appreciate any help in this matter. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the Python code I have in JupyterLab:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix, plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score
def main():
    st.title("Binary Classification Web App")
```

Note: Yes, I installed streamlit using 'pip install streamlit' in the Anaconda command shell. I also am getting the aforementioned NumExpr message when I try to test streamlit with 'streamlit hello' in the shell.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I should have specified. Here is the code I have in JupyterLab above:

Comment: Running your code did not produce this error, maybe take a look at this discussion [Numexpr.utils: NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/numexpr-utils-numexpr-defaulting-to-8-threads/19804).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> numexpr.utils: NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.

Is just an `INFO` message. You can safely ignore it.

I believe the reason that you don't see the app in the browser is because you didn't call the `main` function. Try calling `main` or moving `st.title` to the global scope.

P.S. Here is the "customary" way of doing this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```